# Making Sense Out of The IUPAC Exo/Endo Definition

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature

[image: IUPAC exo/endo definition]

Am I missing something or is the IUPAC endo/exo definition completely illogical? The prefixes exo- and endo- in general (also in chemistry) mean away (outwards) and towards (into), respectively. The chemical names under the shown structures are correct (e.g. it is 2-exo-bromo because the Br group is pointing away from the highest numbered bridge which is "y" based on the general structure on the left). Did IUPAC mess up the bridge numbering and what followed usage of towards/away in respect to exo- and endo-?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. The names are correct and so are the descriptions. What's the problem? How is the bridge numbering 'messed up'?

Comment: In the definition they write: "If the group is oriented towards the highest numbered bridge ('z' bridge, e.g. C-7 in example below) it is given the description 'exo';" First, the 'z' bridge is the lowest numbered bridge. The C-7 group is on the 'x' bridge so we are comparing it relative to the 'y' bridge which is higher numbered than 'z'.  Finally, an exo group is oriented away not towards the highest numbered bridge. I'm really confused ;/

Answer (score 2):

I think OP confused about numbering scheme. I hope following diagram would explain what is meant by the highest and lowest numbered bridges:

[image: Explanation of exo-endo & syn-anti]

Also, the example given in Gold Book do not do the justice because two bridges are same numbered (2-corners). If it was bicyclo[3.2.1]octane instead of bicyclo[2.2.1]heptane, then lowest numbered bridge would have been 3-corner bridge with numbers 2,3,4 (bridge heads are 1 and 5) and highest numbered bridge would have been 1-corner bridge (8).

Comment: thanks for your input. I thought the bridge numbering was based on the length and not on atom numbering. This would make a bit more sense now. However, I still believe IUPACs word combination of 'highest/lowest numbered bridge' with 'towards/away' and 'exo/endo' is misfortunate. In my opinion, exo- should be associated with away/outward and endo- with towards/inward.  This, however, would be incompatible with the highest/lowest bridge based on carbon numbering rather then the number of atoms that make up the bridge.